# "ls" command stuck trying to list a stale mount point. How do you kill/stop it?

Tags: command-line, ls, remote

When working with remote file systems such as `sshfs` or `smbfs`, it might happen that the file systems become stale due to network problems. To check if the mount is stale or not, I usually use the command `ls` to see if I can list the contents of the remote mounts. When these remote mounts are stale, the `ls` command just waits for a long time until outputting, after some minutes, something along the lines of:

```
ls: cannot access '/mnt/remote': Input/output error
```

Instead of waiting for this error, is there a way to stop the `ls` command from **within the same bash session**? The regular Control+C does not seem to do the job. Closing the bash shell works, but this is undesirable. Any alternatives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, since `ls` (or any other file-operating process) is in the process state "uninterruptible sleep", there is nothing that can interrupt it, even `SIGKILL` can't.

Maybe you can lower the timeout values when mounting remote filesystems. `sshfs` has [`ServerAliveInterval` and `ServerAliveCountMax`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man5/ssh_config.5).

Comment: Filesystem operations are seen as "short waits" and are not interruptable. If your OS supports a forced unmount, you may do this and then kill the `ls` as it then no longer waits to an existing filesystem.

Comment: @schily That would make a good answer. It fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to kill `ls`, rather **fix the source of the issue**: the stale mount point.
Unmount it!

A normal `umount` might not work when the connection got lost, then you can use `umount -l`:

> **-l, --lazy**
> Lazy unmount.  Detach the filesystem from the file hierarchy now, and clean up all references to this filesystem as soon as it is not busy anymore.
> [...]
> The recommended use-case for umount -l is to prevent hangs on shutdown due to an unreachable network share where a normal  umount will hang due to a downed server or a network partition.

```
sudo umount -l /path/to/mountpoint
```

You could try "normal" `umount` first, and if it fails `umount -l, e.g.:

```
sudo timeout 10 umount /path/to/mountpoint \
|| sudo umount -l /path/to/mountpoint
```

Answer (score 0):

To stop all `ls` processes:

```
pkill --signal SIGKILL ls
```

Comment: Is there a way, however, to stop the "ls" process within the same bash session? i.e.: without opening a new bash shell